# Enable featuregate EKS via eksctl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, csi

I want to enable feature gate in EKS Cluster because I want to use `io2` PVC. I am following this document. https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver and it says the following. However, in `eksctl` I cannot see any option to create a node group enabling these features or passing these options.

How will I do that?

```
Enable flag --allow-privileged=true for kubelet and kube-apiserver
Enable kube-apiserver feature gates --feature-gates=CSINodeInfo=true,CSIDriverRegistry=true,CSIBlockVolume=true,VolumeSnapshotDataSource=true
Enable kubelet feature gates --feature-gates=CSINodeInfo=true,CSIDriverRegistry=true,CSIBlockVolume=true
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue, we don't have to enable feature gate as such for EKS. for io2 we have to use the alpha version of CSI driver not the stable one. If you use stable versionand try io2 PVC it will fail.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you learned that you didn't need to enable those feature gates? I'm following the same guide but I'm struggling to find out how to convert my existing PVs.

Comment: @schemanic if you are using EKS atleast 1.17 , You dont have to do that.